# Is there any fix for the high CPU usage of Gala?

Tags: release-loki, gala, cpu

I've been keeping attention to processes in my laptop and gala is constantly in the top 3 places, many times using more then 100% of the CPU. I think that is what was been slowing down my computer, because other then that, i just use Firefox.. I've been using linux from less then 1 month, its normal to be slow as windows after some months of use?

Answer (score 1):

It's not normal for it to be so slow. There might be a corrupt package. Try reinstalling gala.

Open synaptic package manager by typing it in the applications menu search bar. Let it load. Once done, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and search for libmutter. It will display a list of packages. If you right click on any of them it will display the option for marking package for reinstallation,removal, etc. Mark the following packages for reinstallation:

`gala`, `libgala0`, `libmutter0g`

Click Edit > Apply Marked Changes. Click Apply on summary window.

Reboot your computer.

Please check back to tell us if this helps.

Comment: As an aside, how did you markup the shortcut keys?

Comment: @MikeWild I think SE as a whole defines CSS styles for the `<kbd>` html tag, which is what I used. Tests: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> | `<kbd> CTRL</kbd>` I'm not sure what escape sequence the editor accepts. Although it's possible to achieve the same effects in the comments, I'm not sure how  it's done. As you can see, at least the first didn't render as it was intended. Also, since I've been curious about the various things people have done with their answers and posts on SE, just clicking on edit without actually editing anything reveals a lot... In case you've been wondering about other posts as well.

Comment: Heh thanks, I didn't even realise that the `<kbd>` tag existed!

Comment: @MikeWild You'd be surprised just what tags the W3C has up its sleeves. If you're ever bored out of your mind: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Gala (Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki virtualized in VirtualBox 5.2.14 on a Mac with OS 10.11.6). After killing the gala process and running the command "gala -r &" in the background, the CPU shows a normal behavior again.

It's just a workaround.